# Form does not close when shown using ShowDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms derived from a base form.

In the base form I have subscribed to the `FormClosing` event.
When the form is being closed, I check if the save changes prompt has been shown.

If the user has not been prompted to save changes, I:

- cancel the form close
- show the save prompt
- set the prompted bool
- then use `Close()` to close the form.

The issue is that after the prompt has been shown to the user, my call to `Close()` does not close the form.

```
protected bool _savePromptShown;

private void PromptUnsavedChanges()
{
    if (_isDirty)
    {
        // Prompt and save code here..
    }

    _savePromptShown = true;

    Close();
}

private void ValueCollectionsForm_FormClosing(
    object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_savePromptShown)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        PromptUnsavedChanges();
    }
}
```

I have tried reproducing the issue in a blank test form and in forms derived from that form.
The reproduction worked as expected, and the form closes as expected.
This was tested by setting the test form as the starting form.

I have used breakpoints to examine the condition and ensure the form closing event is indeed being called the second time when `Close()` is called.  All of this operates as expected, however the form does not close.
The forms do close after clicking the `X` again.

The forms that do not work are being shown using

```
new MyDerivedForm().ShowDialog(this);
```

When I set the form as the starting form (in Program.cs) the form(s) close as expected.

I suspect the way I am showing the form may be the cause for the issue, but am unsure how to resolve the issue.

I am using `ShowDialog` because the main form should not be interacted with while any of these sub forms are open.

Using `Show` does allow the form to close correctly, however this allows the main form to be interacted with.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to close the form if something goes wrong in the "prompt and save code " block, that function should probably a boolean.  Then it would be `e.Cancel = !PromptUnsavedChanges();`  You can get rid of the `Close();` then, too.

Comment: You shouldn't subscribe to events in your own base Form. You should override the methods (`OnFormClosing()`, here)

Comment: @LarsTech I ended up removing the `Cancel` portion, since im closing the form in all cases.  Doing the Cancel and then closing after was a stupid idea, not sure what my thought process was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact issue is, but I cannot see this working well.

My guess is that the `Close`-call is being ignored, since it is called from the `Closing`-event. After you have done all your prompting, saving, etc, you cancel the close-call, thus preventing the form from being closed.

The first thing I would try is to remove `e.Cancel = true;` and `Close();`, that should let the close process progress normally.

If that does not work, try changing  `PromptUnsavedChanges();` to `this.BeginInvoke(PromptUnsavedChanges)`, that should cancel the closing of the form, and a short time later run the `PromptUnsavedChanges` method that has the opportunity to reattempt the close.

Comment: Yeah I ended up removing the cancel close loop and it works fine.  My thought process was flawed, not sure why I went that route..  All is working fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This ***ValueCollectionsForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)***  event handler is called when From.Close() is called.
Inside this method, you are calling the ***PromptUnsavedChanges()*** method and inside this you called the Close() again. So that the closing event is being called for the second time.

These two thing you need to consider:

1. Remove the Close() from the ***PromptUnsavedChanges()***, and then it will call once only.
2. Probably because of the flag ***_savePromptShown*** issue the Form is not closing correctly.